# Flex monthUTC indexed differently from dateUTC and FullYearUTC

Tags: apache-flex, date

I'm having fun with dates in flex, and had a strange bug showing up. It turned out to be not-really-a-bug, but a somewhat strange way of the way Flex works with dates. Namely,

`dateSelected.selectedDate.fullYearUTC` returns 4 digit year number, 
`dateSelected.selectedDate.dateUTC` returns day number, from 1 to 31, while
`dateSelected.selectedDate.monthUTC` returns month number from 0 to 11 (!!!).

What's up with that? Is there some good reason not all fields are treated the same way? I kinda guess there is, but was unable to find the 'why' part.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the handling of dates in ActionScript (and *many* other languages) certainly is not ideal, there actually is a somewhat understandable logic to this:

You have to picture the inner workings of the Date class as arrays. While the year and date numbers are *assigned* to a period of time (think of it as the array's **value** at a specified index ) - the day of the week, month, etc., represent the index number (think of it as the array's **key**).

In flex, index numbers start at 0, so try to picture these arrays in code:

```
var months:Array = ["January", "February",...];
// months [0] => "January"
// (Date.monthUTC returns the index number)
var daysOfWeek:Array = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",...];
// daysOfWeek [2] => "Tuesday"
// (Date.dayUTC returns the index number)
```

and these are most interesting:

```
var date:Array = [1,2,3,4,...];
// date [0] => 1
// (Date.dateUTC returns the value)
var years:Array = [1970, 1971, 1972,...];
// year[0] => 1970
// (Date.fullYearUTC returns the value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex uses zero-based arrays. So, an array containing month names in Flex

```
var monthNames:Array=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
```

Will give you `January` at `monthNames[0]`.

To keep in line with this concept, the `date.monthUTC` or the `date.month` return one less than what you would be writing manually as the month number.

I believe many other languages also behave similarly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate, I upped both your answers, as they are both good, but I picked weltraumpirat's since he was more detailed.